# GetAsyncKeyState(0x57) works fine, but not GetAsyncKeyState('w')

Tags: c++

So, yeah, 0x41 is 'w', but why is this

```
GetAsyncKeyState(0x57)
```

working and this

```
GetAsyncKeyState('w')
```

is not working? By "not working", I mean that when I press 'w', it does not react at all as it does with 0x57.  How can I fix it? What I want to do is read a character from a file, like 'w', and then use it in GetAsyncKeyState() function. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The ASCII code `0x41` is the character `'A'`.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that, fixed it, but it still not working.

Comment: By the way, have you tried using [`std::toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper)? `'w' != 'W'`

Comment: 0x57 is not 'w', it is 'W'.

Comment: Again you are right! Thank you very much! Uppercase works perfect. But wait, why is UPPERCASE working? I do not have my CAPSLOCK on!

Comment: @user3496846 `GetAsyncKeyState` works on keys. There is only one key. The issue of upper and lower case is handled higher up the chain.

Comment: @David Heffernan thank you, this answers my question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ASCII code for `'w'` is `0x77` and the ASCII code for `'W'` is `0x57`. So

```
GetAsyncKeyState(0x57)
```

is the same as

```
GetAsyncKeyState('W')
```

which is different from

```
GetAsyncKeyState('w')
```

The official [table of virtual key codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731.aspx) gives `0x57` as the code for the <kbd>W</kbd> key.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you must pass a [virtual key code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). For the <kbd>w</kbd> key the virtual key code is 0x57, which is 'W' and not 'w'.